# How/why does npm recommend not running as root?

Tags: node.js, npm

### In short...

First of all, why does [npm](http://npmjs.org/) suggest that it should only run as non-root? I highly disbelieve that every other package manager (`apt`, `yum`, `gem`, `pacman`) is wrong for requiring sudo.

Second, when I follow their suggestion (and run `npm install` as non-root), it won't work (because non-root doesn't have permission to /usr/local/lib). How do I follow their suggestion? I am not going to `chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib`, because that seems like a very bad idea to me.

### Full description...

I installed [npm](http://npmjs.org/) via `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` (the instruction in their README).

When I run `sudo npm install mongoose`, npm tells me not to run it as root:

```
npm ERR! sudon't!
npm ERR! sudon't! Running npm as root is not recommended!
npm ERR! sudon't! Seriously, don't do this!
npm ERR! sudon't!
```

But when I run `npm install mongoose` without sudo I get the following:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@0.2.17
npm info using node@v0.4.0-pre
npm info fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/-/mongoose-1.0.7.tgz
npm info calculating sha1 /tmp/npm-1297199132405/1297199132406-0.7044695958029479/tmp.tgz
npm info shasum b3573930a22066fbf3ab745a79329d5eae75b8ae
npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/.cache/mongoose/1.0.7/package.tgz
npm ERR! Failed creating the tarball.
npm ERR! This is very rare. Perhaps the 'gzip' or 'tar' configs
npm ERR! are set improperly?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! couldn't pack /tmp/npm-1297199132405/1297199132406-0.7044695958029479/contents/package to /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/.cache/mongoose/1.0.7/package.tgz
npm ERR! Error installing mongoose@1.0.7
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/.cache/mongoose'
npm ERR! There appear to be some permission problems
npm ERR! See the section on 'Permission Errors' at
npm ERR!   http://github.com/isaacs/npm#readme
npm ERR! This will get better in the future, I promise.
npm not ok
```

So it tells me I shouldn't use sudo, and then doesn't work if I follow their suggestion.

Which leads to my initial questions above.

Comment: Here's now my understanding. Other package managers like `apt` are supposed to run as root (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) because they are built correctly. `npm` is not finished with their product completely, so npm _ought_ to be runnable as root, but they haven't finished that feature yet (https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/294). Until they do, it is actually unsafe to run as sudo.

Comment: Because the guy who wrote it is really irritating, is all I can figure out.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Actually, npm does **not** recommend not running as root. Well, not any more.

It has changed around the same time that you asked your question. This is how the README looked like on February 7, 2011: *"Using sudo with npm is Very Not Recommended. Anyone can publish anything, and package installations can run arbitrary scripts."* It was explained later in more detail as *"Option 4: HOLY COW NOT RECOMMENDED!! You can just use sudo all the time for everything, and ignore the incredibly obnoxious warnings telling you that you're insane for doing this."*

See: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/tree/7288a137f3ea7fafc9d4e7d0001a8cd044d3a22e#readme

Now it is actually considered a *recommended* technique of installing npm:

> *Simple Install - To install npm with one command, do this:*
>
> *curl http:/ /npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh*

See: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/tree/99f804f43327c49ce045ae2c105995636c847145#readme

My advice would be to **never do it** because it means basically this:

1. find out what the local DNS (or anyone else spoofing the DNS response or poisoning the DNS cache) says is the IP address of npmjs.org
2. connect with insecure TCP with that IP (or with whoever says it's his IP) on port 80
3. trust the router that you think you should talk to (or anyone who gave you the DHCP response said you should talk to) to deliver packets to the right host
4. possibly go through another layer of transparent caching proxy
5. trust all other networks between you and the other end of the TCP connection
6. don't know for sure who you are connected with
7. cross your fingers
8. request install.sh script over insecure HTTP with no verification whatsoever
9. and then run whatever was returned by whoever you're talking to with maximum privileges on your machine without even checking what is it.

As you can see this is really, literally, with no exaggeration giving **root shell** to *whatever you get* after asking for a script from the Internet over an insecure connection with *no verification whatsoever*. There are at least 5 different things that can go wrong here, any of which can lead to an attacker taking total control over your machine:

1. DHCP spoofing
2. ARP spoofing
3. DNS cache poisoning
4. DNS response spoofing
5. TCP session hijacking

Also note that using 'sh' instead of 'sudo sh' is usually not any less risky unless you run it as a different user who doesn't have access to your private data, which is usually not the case.

You should use HTTPS connections if available to download such scripts so you could at least verify who you are talking to, and even then I wouldn't run it without reading first. Unfortunately npmjs.org has a self-signed certificate so it doesn't really help in this case.

Fortunately npm is available on GitHub that has a valid SSL certificate and from where you can download it using secure connection. See: github.com/isaacs/npm for details. But make sure that the npm itself doesn't use insecure connections to download the files that it downloads - there should be an option in npm config.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for that well thought out response! This helps me install npm without such security problems. However, once I install npm, my other part of the question still isn't answered. In other words, I can _install_ npm now, but how do I _use_ npm? do I run `npm` as root or not?

Comment: @Zed Nice thoughts, but they don't really help you. As soon as you clone a git repo and run its makefile, you could be infected. As soon as you install just one malicious npm package, you could be infected. Also, as long as your account is able to `sudo` and you sometimes use it for that, not being root while getting infected has ~zero impact on the attackers abilities to do evil stuff.

Comment: @thejh My advises don't help you if the software itself is malicious as intended by its author. But it helps in a much more probable situation where the software is fine but you are indeed not talking to the author but to someone who wants to serve you a trojaned version of that software. If you get the official version from GitHub then it is in my opinion much less likely that it is malicious. But of course being or not being root is pretty much irrelevant anyway since your private files in $HOME are usually the most important as I said, plus there is sudo as you said. 100% agree on that.

Comment: npmjs now use a https connection with DigiCert as Authority so you're quite sure who you're talking with.

Answer (score 22):

The simple answer is web servers should never be run as root for well known security reasons, so this goes for npm commands as well.

To start fresh, remove prior [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and npm installs as well as these files/directories:

```
mv ~/.npmrc       ~/.npmrc~prior
mv ~/.npm         ~/.npm~prior
mv ~/tmp          ~/tmp.~prior
mv ~/.npm-init.js ~/.npm-init.js~prior
```

Solution: Install Node.js (which comes with npm) as NON root (no sudo)

Download Source Code directly from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Execute the below as yourself (Linux/OS X)

```
cd node-v8.1.2  # into expanded source dir

export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/node-v8.1.2 # put this into your ~/.bashrc
```

Feel free to change above export to whatever location is appropriate

```
./configure   --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}
make -j4   # for dual core ... use  -j8  for quad core CPU
make install
```

which puts the binaries for Node.js and npm as well as its modules repository into $NODE_PARENT, a $USER owned dir which then allows you to issue subsequent npm install xxx commands as yourself.

To reach the binaries for node and npm alter your PATH environment variables in your ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules
```

Then to install packages into that directory (global), as opposed to the current directory (local) always pass in the -g flag (global):

```
npm install -g someModule
```

NOTE - at no time are you executing anything npm or node related as root / sudo.

Comment: Thanks Scott, this helped me a lot after a complete uninstall

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for **not** installing NPM packages under root is that it will cause you to face file access problem with packages that are using node-gyp (ex: node-sass) because it builds C++ libs and those are not in the local `node_modules` folder.