# Node express now

Tags: node.js, express, nowjs-sockets

I want to rewrite a complete community website in nodejs,express and
nowjs with mongodb. Its currently in php using the codeigniter
framework. It includes functionality such as your own profile page,
photoalbum, guestbook, internal messages, contacts and more. And im
going to add an im to it and some other things like a forum and so on.
Its a pretty big project.

I have to make a decision about which techniques to use in the
webapplication. So i did a little research and found, node, Expess and
nowjs.
Should i stick to finish the application in php( codeigniter ), mysql
and ajax, or can i do this in express, mongodb and nowjs?

Can anyone recommend this for use on a live production site? And if
so, are there any security issues one should know about? General
guidelines?

Help would be really appreciated so i can make up my mind and finish
the project

Regards

George

Comment: deployment might be an issue ( i sayd: might be )

Comment: Well thats not gonna be an issue because i have my own server. Im thinking more of issues like security etc, sessions, people getting access to information from database and so on...

Comment: Im thinking that its so young, are there any risks people know about. Should one wait a few years before bulding a large project in node and express, so the security holes and bugs are found and fixed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Nodejs being young is not that it's a half baked product or something but infact it's growing very fast and new developments are being done at breath taking place. So you need to keep up with them while developing.

Otherwise there are huge projects out there developed totally with node and express. Take a look at expressjs.com/applications to see what kind of commericial projects are built using it.

As far as security, sessions etc. are concerned. Unlike ASP/PHP , you don't get most of the features out of the box. You'll need to either write them yourselves or using open source frameworks. Both ways you and only you have to ensure that your application has all bases covered. With flexibility, comes complexity.

It should be noted that Nodejs is optimum for real time I/O. If you think this is something which is required at your end then I highly recommend to go for it.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the reply.

Actually the only parts of the site that 'need' realtime io, is a chat between members that added eachother to their contactlist. All other parts of the site can do without it.It would be nice to have a fast application and be able to push everything. e.g. if a member posts a new ad or uploads a new picture and members in the contactlist see an update in realtime. Im still using ajax to do some of the stuff, so why not get rid off php and ajax and use node for everything.
How much of the security stuff is done in express? Any recommendations for security frameworks?

Comment: Not sure about security frameworks but this strategy makes a lot of sense > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259291/security-in-node-js-webserver . For chat, node.js is great. wompt.com is built on nodejs/express/mongodb. Sockets are great but are not supported in every browser.

Comment: @George Node.js would replace the PHP, but not the AJAX. You will still need to write traditional browser-based JavaScript to send asynchronous requests to your Node server.

Comment: @AndreiM: If he goes with WebSockets (which he mentioned in the question) then sockets will effectively replace all the AJAX code.

Comment: gotcha. I wasn't familiar with nowjs.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe does sound like a big project.

If you have the time to spare, I would suggest picking a small portion of it that deals with managing secure sessions (e.g. the profile page). Implement that in Express to get a sense of how it compares to the existing PHP. If you like it, keep going.

Particularly when security is at stake, always try to use existing components when they are available. Node's minimalism makes it tempting to 'roll your own,' but it's very easy to make a security mistake with anything less than expert knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! :)

I posted this question in the express-js google group too, and i got an answer mentioning https. Think thats a good way to go as an extra layer of security.

Im gonna try it out as you suggested, and then make up my mind. But i think im leaning to rewriting the whole site :)

Thank you everybody :)