# Permission denied when installing Browsersync via NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I can't install Browsersync https://www.browsersync.io/#install to my Mac OS Sierra. I installed node.js and after running command

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

I'm getting error. What I'm doing wrong?

```
pavels-iMac:~ Pavel$ npm install -g browser-sync

npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/Pavel/.npm/browser-sync/2.17.2/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "browser-sync"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Pavel/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: ostrov you should unaccept my answer and accept @msanford's

Comment: What a gent, @brandonscript!:)

Comment: I can admit when I'm wrong. Just because I trusted some people to teach me the 'right' way of doing it, doesn't mean I can't learn the error of my ways 

Comment: @brandonscript Similarly, I didn't know about the real dangers of chowning local, nice HN link.

Comment: I don't like either solution tbh. I think npm has some work to do.

Comment: @msanford interesting find: https://github.com/npm/npm/search?utf8=✓&q=unsafe. Via aredridel on Twitter. Looking into this further!

Answer (score 2):

There are [two officially-suggested methods for fixing this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions):

1. Direct npm to install modules globally [somewhere your user owns](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory) by issuing `npm config set prefix ~./some/folder` and adding `~./some/folder/bin` to your `$PATH`.
2. Change the ownership of a subset of /usr/local to your user.

   `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

However, the first solution seems the most sound. I don't necessarily think one should be mucking around with system permissions anyway.

Further discussion on  [How/why does npm recommend not running as root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938592/how-why-does-npm-recommend-not-running-as-root)

Answer (score 1):

It's commonly recommended to give ownership of /usr/local/ to your user account. This location is used by npm global modules as well as many mac Homebrew packages.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

This should fix your problem and also prevent you from having to use sudo unnecessarily.

Comment: It's not a security issue. The directory isn't used by Apple.

See https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md

Comment: This is (close to) the officially-suggested solution; https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: Running sudo every time you call npm is probably more of a security issue than changing an empty, unused directory like /usr/local AWAY from root permissions (that's less permission than it had).

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issue on Mac macOS Sierra.

I suggest using safer approach which I followed and it worked i.e. Instead of CHOWN whole /usr/local folder.

If you have installed Node via Homebrew then you will have it already just fine, you just need to CHOWN the node_modules folder i.e.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

So we fix the permissions for the only directory we are having issue with.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

is sufficient to run.

Comment: Please consider improving the quality of your response. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."