# How to fix npm update error? (# npm install npm@latest -g)

Tags: node.js, npm

How to fix npm update error? I run as root

> # npm install npm@latest -g

```
usr/lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Linux 4.10.14-200.fc25.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "npm@latest" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

And end up without npm.

The log file is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/2maxolbxjlnnp7c/npm-debug_error.log.txt?dl=0

my node version is 6.10.2, using fedora core 25 64bits. The npm version was 3.10.10

I also create an issue on https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/168

Now, npm is not installed:

> ## npm
>
> -bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory

I'm following the https://github.com/brock/node-reinstall tomorrow, trying a full node uninstall and reinstall if no other advise found.

I run this npm update since it's the sugested first step for installing polymer-cli in polymer 2.0

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli

Comment: Why not try use `npm update npm`?

Comment: Please, don't run it as root user!

Comment: I run this command since it's the first sugested step for installing polymer2. Check https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli

Comment: I see a very similar bug in the past (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/898) that was closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve the issue, running as root

```
# dnf remove nodejs
# dnf install nodejs
```

Comment: And not troubles running as root? Well if it worked, fantastic!

Comment: this then `npm i -g npm-upgrade` worked out on fedora

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, I do not recommend running npm commands as root user, check this question and answer for [recommendations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938592/how-why-does-npm-recommend-not-running-as-root) Running npm as root could cause you problems in the future.

You can update npm using npm as follows:

```
npm i -g npm-upgrade
```

If you have permission errors, [check here how to fix them](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Now for your particular error, it seems that you must erase the folder:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp
```

I recommend removing your node and installing it again.

Comment: I already rename node-gyp to node-gyp_old. But now i don't have a working npm

Comment: If I where you, I would erase all the folders, uninstall the NPM, and install it again, not with root, and run the update command not with root user

Comment: yes. "dnf remove nodejs" and "dnf install nodejs" as root solve the issue.

Comment: Fantastic! Don't forget accept the answer if it was useful to you :)

Answer (score 6):

try with sudo

```
sudo npm i -g npm@latest
```